# Jupiternote book on iPad / makrdown cells / how to drag a picture?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I use JUNO connect to run cocalc on my iPad.
How can I get a picture in my picture file on the iPad into a markdown cell?
Thanks a lot for any help!